# add custom order status to orders grid bulk actions in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.4, order-status, order-grid

How to add more order statuses to orders grid bulk actions drop down to update one or more orders status at a time by selecting the check box of orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the file `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`, and scroll to the `massaction` node.

This is how Magento added its own bulk actions for the existing states.

In your own module, you will need to create a `sales_order_grid.xml` file (typically something like `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`).
In this file, you will need to add your own `action` nodes for your custom states.

Here is an example of what your file could look like (not tested, you might have to modify it a bit) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="customstate">
                <settings>
                    <url path="customroute/order/massCustomsate"/>
                    <type>customstate</type>
                    <label translate="true">Custom State</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

In this example, you will have to edit :

- the action name : to match your custom state
- the url path : to match with your custom controller (you'll have to create a custom admin route and Controller)
- the type : to match with your custom state code
- the label : To match with your custom state Label

For the custom controller, take a look at the existing classes, like this one :
`\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassCancel`.